# Different Paths for AuthUserFile based on different hosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to set up an .htaccess/.htpasswd pair on my servers however, each environment (dev, staging, production) has different paths for where the files will sit.

I found a way to check the environment based on the host, which is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:stage]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production]
```

but now I want to be able to use a conditional to set the paths of the AuthUserFile based on the environment.

So I guess my questions are:

1. Is this even possible?
2. Is there anyway to have one file for all environment and just change the path based on the host name ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I had arrived here asking the same question and now that I have found a solution, I have come back to share it.

According to [Apache's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile), the AuthUserFile parameter takes a file-path as an argument. This

> (...)file-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it
> is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.

So the easy way seems to take advantage of this behaviour using a relative path for the file, that will pretty sure the same across all environments.

Edit: Further search has revealed two differents ways of solving this: Using [simlynks](https://serverfault.com/a/313643) or [conditionals](http://%3CIf%20%22req(%27Host%27)%20=%20%27www.example.com%27%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20Authtype%20Basic%20%20%20%20%20AuthName%20%22user%20and%20password%22%20%20%20%20%20AuthUserFile%20/var/www/www.example.com/.htpasswd%20%20%20%20%20Require%20valid-user%20%3C/If%3E)